# Nestjs e2e testing of an application within a monorepo fails to resolve @app import from library with jest despite config in package.json

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, nestjs-testing

I'm trying to run e2e tests for a monorepo application that also utilises several libraries from within the monorepo, all imports throughout the application are resolved using "@app" imports, for example `import { ConfigService } from "@app/config"`

However, when trying to run e2e tests via the command:

```
"test:public": "jest --config ./apps/public-microservice/test/jest-e2e.json",
```

Jest throws:

```
 Cannot find module '@app/config' from '../src/public-microservice.module.ts'
```

I've looked at [this demo-repo from @jmcdo29](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs) and can't find anything that is different with my configuration.

I've noticed there was an issue about wrong configurations being generated via jest [here in 2019](https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/465), but it has long been resolved, and my configuration for jest in package.json does indeed mention:

```
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "@app/config/(.*)": "<rootDir>/libs/config/src/$1",
      "@app/config": "<rootDir>/libs/config/src",
```

whilst the local targeted file by the package.json script command only contains:

```
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": ".",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  }
}
```

Is there something that's missing from my command or my configuration?

Is there anything I need to specify to tell jest to extend the configuration for jest available in package.json?

Any help investingating this is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Comment: yep, I had to copy & update the `jest.moduleNameMapper` value from package.json into the specific test configuration at `/apps/public-microservice/test/jest-e2e.json`--- the CLI only updates the package.json values, not the individual e2e test as you add libs & apps

Comment: @SebastianG could you please add answer with correct configuration please?

Comment: @Sergii added an answer with my specific case

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I added the "moduleNameMapper" key to my jest e2e suite config and updated the "../" relative paths to match where my libs are, in my specific scenario, it looks like this:

```json
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "@app/config/(.*)": "<rootDir>../../../libs/config/src/$1",
    "@app/config": "<rootDir>../../../libs/config/src",
  },
```

Comment: I simplified this to `"moduleNameMapper": {
    "@app/(.*)": "<rootDir>../../../libs/$1/src"
  }`and now it works for every library

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the generated e2e suite config file, we can use the jest cli to override the `testRegex` value in package.json which is used for the unit tests.

In `package.json` change the `test:e2e script` like this:

```
"test:e2e": "jest --testRegex .e2e-spec.ts$"
```

Now you don't have to use an external config for e2e testing, the config as defined in package.json is used for both unit and e2e tests now and only the testRegex is overriden to target e2e tests instead of unit tests when `npm run test:e2e` is called.

This way you only have to configure moduleNameMappers once in package.json.